# JPG & RAW file transfer iPad to MacBook

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, photos, file-transfer

How can JPG & RAW files be transferred from iPad to MacBook Pro & still maintain the albums built in iPad?

In the iPad Photos app I've put my photos in different albums. On iPad I'm using Photos & Affinity Photo. On my Macbook I've used Photos, Image Capture and iTunes & they import everything but not the albums, which is daunting because I've got 10,000 photos I'm importing. Which is also the problem with iCloud because it wants to backup everything & it's not obvious that it also imports the albums (at least Apple Support can't confirm that either)>

Comment: Do you mean albums in the built-in photos app? 
And please add which apps you're using for your photo-library on the iPad and the Mac

Comment: You could do cloud syncing..

Answer (score 1):

Photos app on macOS, via iCloud syncing maintains album structure. If the photos are in albums in photos app on iPad, turning on selectively iCloud for photos app only and turning off backup on iCloud can do what you want to achieve.

[image: Photos side bar screenshot which shows albums of WhatsApp and 9GAG]

Though some offline method would be great too!

Comment: Thank you. That's useful information (you know more than Apple support.) I'll have to get more iCloud storage first to do that since iCloud wants to do all photos & with 10,000 to upload more space needed. An offline method would be nice. I thought once I plugged in my iPad to my Macbook it'd be more or less drag/drop op but apparently Apple in their wisdom haven't put that functionality into their system.

Answer (score -1):

@ankii Thank you. That's useful information (you know more than Apple support.) I'll have to get more iCloud storage first to do that since iCloud wants to do all photos & with 10,000 to upload more space needed. An offline method would be nice. I thought once I plugged in my iPad to my Macbook it'd be more or less drag/drop op but apparently Apple in their wisdom haven't put that functionality into their system.